# Not able to send mail via LOCAL xampp server

Tags: php, xampp

**PHP CODE BELOW:** Already done configuration in php.ini & sendmail.ini

```
<?php
$to_email = "receipient@gmail.com";
$subject = "Simple Email Test via PHP";
$body = "Hi,nn This is test email send by PHP Script";
$headers = "From: sender\'s email";
 
if (mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "Email successfully sent to $to_email...";
} else {
    echo "Email sending failed...";
}
```

**Getting the following error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To insert a PHP variable in a string you have to use curly brackets.

Like this:

```
<?php
$to_email = "receipient@gmail.com";
$subject = "Simple Email Test via PHP";
$body = "Hi,nn This is test email send by PHP Script";
$headers = "From: sender's email";

if (mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo "Email successfully sent to {$to_email}..."; // <-- here the brackets
} else {
    echo "Email sending failed...";
}
```

Comment: The `{}` are optional (although they can affect the syntax of the variable name).

Comment: Getting this error,   Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.